# Ajax Call to send Email Not working.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am very much new to JQuery. Guys can any one tell me what is wrong with my code I want to send an email through ajax and then populate a returned string in a div. I am trying to send the data from my view to my controller use the data and then send back a string to add in the Dom. How can i do that. Thanks in anticipation for your time and efforts. Cheers.

**My View**

```
<!-- Contact form -->
                <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" data-name="Contact Form">

                    <div class="row">

                        <!-- Full name -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="name" class="form form-control" placeholder="Write your name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write your name'" name="name" data-name="Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- E-mail -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" id="email" class="form form-control" placeholder="Write your email address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write your email address'" name="email" data-name="Email Address" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Subject -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="subject" class="form form-control" placeholder="Write the subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write the subject'" name="subject" data-name="Subject">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Message -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea id="text-area" class="form textarea form-control" placeholder="Your message here... 20 characters Min." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your message here... 20 characters Min.'" name="message" data-name="Text Area" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Button submit -->
                    <button type="submit" id="valid-form" class="btn btn-color">Send my Message</button>

                </form>
                <!-- /. Contact form -->

                <div id="block-answer">
                    <div id="answer"></div>
                </div>
```

**Script at the end of Body**

```
$('#valid-form').click(function () {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var subject = $('#subject').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/SendMessage',
            data: { 'name': name, 'email': email, 'subject': subject, 'message': message },
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            success: function (status) {
                $('#answer').text(savingStatus);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('#answer').text("Error encountered while saving the message.");
            }
        });
    });
```

**My Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public string SendMessage(string name, string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        var savingStatus = "Success";
        return savingStatus;
    }
```

Comment: I do see a typo in your success function.  It should say ```$('#answer').text(status);```

Comment: Just do `data: $(this).serialize(),`. You don't need to get the value for each input individually and then create a JS object out of that.

Comment: Even if this is true sir. How will i hit the controller.

Comment: I assumed based on the id that this was the id for your form, but missed the use of `click`, so now I'm not sure what this is. Regardless, the only thing that would prevent it from hitting your controller is either 1) the element identified by `#valid-form` is not actually getting clicked, or 2) the URL `/Home/SendMessage` does not actually route to where you think it does.

Comment: Your also not cancelling the default submit - `$('#valid-form').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); .....`

Answer (score 0):

You are using string as field names, please replace data with this.

```
data: { name: name, email: email, subject: subject, message: message },
```

Comment: please use site url before controller name

Comment: add complete url for controller

Comment: How to give complete and valid URL. as i am new so i have tried all

Comment: .net 4 i think! and mvc 4